# MySQL silently refusing to create foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a very simple database in MySQL (stripped down example below). The tables are created correctly, and the primary key constraint is created correctly, and the indexes for the foreign key constraints are created correctly, but the foreign key constraints are not created. There is no - repeat - no error message associated with the DDL execution. I've stared at this so long I can't see it any more.

Things I've verified:

1. MySQL v5.1.73
2. I have * permissions on the database
3. Default engine is MyISAM
4. Primary key constraint is created.
5. Foreign key indices are created.

Can someone see an error, or suggest a way forward?

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Sample CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LocationCode CASCADE;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS SampleTypeCode CASCADE;

CREATE TABLE Sample (
    sample VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    location VARCHAR(50),
    sampleType VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (sample)
) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


CREATE TABLE LocationCode (
    code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    text VARCHAR(50),
    sequence INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (code)
) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;


CREATE TABLE SampleTypeCode (
    code VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    text TEXT,
    sequence INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (code)
) ENGINE = MyISAM DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

ALTER TABLE Sample ADD CONSTRAINT
    FOREIGN KEY (location) REFERENCES LocationCode (code);

ALTER TABLE Sample ADD CONSTRAINT
    FOREIGN KEY (sampleType) REFERENCES SampleTypeCode (code);
```

When I get the DDL from MySQL, this is what it produces, so it leads me to believe that it's not creating the constraints at all.

```
ALTER TABLE Sample DROP PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE Sample DROP INDEX location;
ALTER TABLE Sample DROP INDEX sampleType;

DROP TABLE Sample;

CREATE TABLE Sample (
  sample VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  location VARCHAR(50),
  sampleType VARCHAR(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (sample)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE INDEX location ON Sample (location ASC);
CREATE INDEX sampleType ON Sample (sampleType ASC);
ALTER TABLE Sample ADD PRIMARY KEY (sample);
```

Comment: MyISAM doesn't support foreign key constraints. You need to use InnoDB.

Comment: And upgrade to a version of MySQL from the current decade. :-)